# regular expressions matching multiline expression

Tags: regex, multiline

I should match this text using the regex-find tool of the texStudio editor

```
\begin{displaymath}
\DIFdel{
```

The problem is that I don't manage to specify the new line (both using the option "dotall" or not). I tried with the pretty generic reference pattern:

```
\\begin\{displaymath\}(\s\S\n\t\r\v)*\\DIFdel\{
```

but is nnot working (of course the pattens "\begin{displaymath}" and "\DIFdel{" match the single parts on the two lines)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex must be,

```
\\begin\{displaymath\}[\s\S]*\\DIFdel\{
```

or

```
\\begin\{displaymath\}\s*\\DIFdel\{
```

`\s\S\n\t\r\v` expects all the mentioned chars to be present. SO there must be a space char,non-space char,newline.... BUt there actually a newline char only.

Comment: it is matching until the newline ([img link](http://it.tinypic.com/r/mrd0t5/8)) , then fails  ([img link](http://it.tinypic.com/r/mujrpg/8))

Comment: ya, `\s*` matches newline char also.

Comment: it is probably some strange interpretation of the regex by the editor, but as you can see is not working ...